# Android: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/mobi27/opt/AND-Studio/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Do you have the latest build tools?

Comment: Yes I have already installed latest build tools

Comment: hey yahska, did you solve it yet?

Comment: sorry. I forgot to update. Conflicting resource was the reason for it. I'll post a link of answer for that.

Answer (score 8):

My solution is: Menu Build -> Clean Project.

I deleted and pasted a picture a while before. The picture has the same problem, so something wrong happened.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I tried to change `buildToolsVersion` in `gradle`, but it didn't help me. My problem was fixed when I found drawable which called  *example.PNG*. It should be *example.png*;

Comment: For me it was with some weird symbols in the name of the image file before .jpeg. Once renamed, it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to install the 32bit dependencies:

`sudo apt-get install -y lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 lib32z1 lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install -y lib32ncurses5 lib32gomp1 lib32z1-dev lib32bz2-dev`

Answer (score 2):

Check if you added a resource that violates the conventions. E.g. cannot have capital letters and such.

In my case I got the error as I had modified a drawable resource and Photoshop saved the image with capital filetype (file_name.PNG). Changing the filename to lower-case and rebuilding the project solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're missing the 22.0.1 build tools. Try going to the Tools>Android>SDK Manager and seeing what version of 'Android SDK Build-tools' you have installed. If it isn't already installed or needs an update, put a checkmark next to the 22.0.1 tools and click install.

Comment: I am also getting a similar error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\C\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1.  I have updated to 22.0.1. The activity file where the error occurs highlights the symbol 'R' which it cannot resolve.

Answer (score 0):

go to Android SDK Manager--->Tool---->check the Android SDK Buil-tolls you have installed, -------------->go to your module's build.gradle--->fill the right "buildToolsVersion"

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have this line in attrs.xml (values folder):

```
<flag name="default" value="0" />
```

**default** - is reserved word, so I renamed it and fixed it!

```
<flag name="font_default" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the build tool version inside app/build.gradle

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
```

Now Clean Project and go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Just a f*king **Invalidate Caches & restart** did the trick for me