# Android Studio Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I try to build my project, the Messages Gradle Build reports these messages:

```
C:\...\src\main\res\values-v14\styles_app.xml
Error:(26, 5) Resource entry Theme.App already has bag item android:windowBackground.
Error:(26, 5) Originally defined here.
C:\...\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(233) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(233) Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(233) Attribute "divider" has already been defined
Error:(233) Attribute "background" has already been defined
Error:(233) Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "title" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "subtitle" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "icon" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "logo" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "backgroundStacked" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "customNavigationLayout" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "homeLayout" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "progressBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "indeterminateProgressStyle" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "progressBarPadding" has already been defined
Error:(261) Attribute "itemPadding" has already been defined
Error:(264) Attribute "initialActivityCount" has already been defined
Error:(264) Attribute "expandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable" has already been defined
Error:(267) Attribute "preserveIconSpacing" has already been defined
Error:(268) Attribute "iconifiedByDefault" has already been defined
Error:(268) Attribute "queryHint" has already been defined
Error:(276) Attribute "track" has already been defined
Error:(276) Attribute "thumbTextPadding" has already been defined
Error:(276) Attribute "switchTextAppearance" has already been defined
Error:(276) Attribute "switchMinWidth" has already been defined
Error:(276) Attribute "switchPadding" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "windowNoTitle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "windowActionModeOverlay" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "windowMinWidthMajor" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "windowMinWidthMinor" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionBarTabStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionBarTabBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionBarTabTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionOverflowButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionBarStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionBarSplitStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionBarWidgetTheme" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionBarSize" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionBarDivider" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionBarItemBackground" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionMenuTextAppearance" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionMenuTextColor" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionModeStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionModeCloseButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionModeBackground" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionModeSplitBackground" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionModeCloseDrawable" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionModeShareDrawable" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionModePopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionDropDownStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "dropdownListPreferredItemHeight" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "spinnerDropDownItemStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "homeAsUpIndicator" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "actionButtonStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "selectableItemBackground" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "dividerVertical" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "activityChooserViewStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "popupMenuStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultTitle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "textColorSearchUrl" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "listPreferredItemHeightSmall" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingRight" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "dropDownListViewStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "listPopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "textAppearanceListItemSmall" has already been defined
Error:(279) Attribute "buttonStyleSmall" has already been defined
C:\...\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

correspondingly in the Gradle Console it is reported:

```
 AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Resource entry Theme.app already has bag item android:windowBackground.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\...\\src\\main\\res\\values-v14\\styles_app.xml","position":{"startLine":25,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1049,"endLine":39,"endColumn":10,"endOffset":2401}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
.
    .
FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

what's the problem?

NOTE: the question reported here  [Android: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781847/android-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources)    is with no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

1) eliminate the android:windowBackground duplicate form values-v14\styles_app.xml;

2) as found in different threads, if you use the "actionBarSherlock" library, you should not use appCompact v7, so you need to set the 7.0.0 version of the play-services in build.gradle project, because this is the last version does not contain it.

3)In the project manifest file you must set:

4) the minSdkVersion version, in librarySlidingMenu gradle file, must not be lower than that set in the Sherlocks library Manifest file.

Comment: Point: 2 was the solution in my case. You just saved a life (y)